# trying to add facebook like button on my website

Tags: javascript, facebook

Below script will downlaod the facebook sdk to generate the code to create the like button

```
  (function() {
            var scrFaceBook = document.createElement('script');
            scrFaceBook.type = 'text/javascript';
            scrFaceBook.src = document.location.protocol +                            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            scrFaceBook.async = true;
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(scrFaceBook);
        })();

<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>
```

I am doing like this to add the FaceBook like button. When I run my application and see I get "object does not support this property or method, all.js, uri: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"

Can some one suggest me how do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `<div id="fb-root"></div>` to the body of the HTML.

Also you seem to have forgotten the APP ID

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=127211380649475";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Comment: what is this 127211380649475.

Comment: The example App ID from Facebook's example...replace it with yours and your page should work better.  Also be sure to include the fb-root div.

Comment: im not sure what appid you are talking about. Can you explain?

Comment: If you have a Facebook app, it comes with an ID.  You'd use that ID there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the dom element is declared above the script tag. Otherwise it might not load:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=127211380649475";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

are your broswer support html5? maybe the error is here "scrFaceBook.async = true;"